# Rewriting function do display complex dictionary to be recursive ( more universal ) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Imput for functions is a complex dictionary:

```
[{'blacklist': [{'devnode': '"^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"'}, {'devnode': '"^hd[a-z][[0-9]*]"'}, {'devnode': '"^cciss!c[0-9]d[0-9]*"'}]}, {'defaults': [{'user_friendly_names': 'yes'}]}, {'defaults': [{'udev_dir': '/dev'}, {'polling_interval': '10'}, {'selector': '"round-robin 0"'}, {'path_grouping_policy': 'multibus'}, {'getuid_callout': '"/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n"'}, {'prio_callout': 'none'}, {'path_checker': 'readsector0'}, {'rr_min_io': '100'}, {'max_fds': '8192'}, {'rr_weight': 'priorities'}, {'failback': 'immediate'}, {'no_path_retry': 'fail'}, {'user_friendly_names': 'yes'}]}, {'blacklist': [{'wwid': '26353900f02796769'}, {'devnode': '"^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"'}, {'devnode': '"^hd[a-z]"'}]}, {'devices': [{'device': [{'vendor': '"COMPAQ "'}, {'product': '"HSV110 (C)COMPAQ"'}, {'path_grouping_policy': 'multibus'}, {'getuid_callout': '"/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n"'}, {'path_checker': 'readsector0'}, {'path_selector': '"round-robin 0"'}, {'hardware_handler': '"0"'}, {'failback': '15'}, {'rr_weight': 'priorities'}, {'no_path_retry': 'queue'}]}, {'device': [{'vendor': '"COMPAQ "'}, {'product': '"MSA1000 "'}, {'path_grouping_policy': 'multibus'}]}]}]
```

I have come up with this function that makes it look as it should with nice indentations:

```
def pretty(d, indent=0):
for i in d:
    for key, value in i.items():
        print('\t' * indent + str(key) + ' {')
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    for key_1, value_1 in item.items():
                        if isinstance(value_1, list):
                            print('\t' * (indent + 2) + str(key_1) + ' {')
                            for x in value_1:
                                for key_2, value_2 in x.items():
                                    print('\t' * (indent + 3) + str(key_2) + 4 * ' ' + str(value_2))
                            print('\t' * (indent + 2) + '}')
                        else:
                            print('\t' * (indent + 1) + str(key_1) + 4 * ' ' + str(value_1))

        print('}')
```

It works the output is nice:

```
    blacklist {
    devnode    "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"
    devnode    "^hd[a-z][[0-9]*]"
    devnode    "^cciss!c[0-9]d[0-9]*"
}
defaults {
    user_friendly_names    yes
}
defaults {
    udev_dir    /dev
    polling_interval    10
    selector    "round-robin 0"
    path_grouping_policy    multibus
    getuid_callout    "/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n"
    prio_callout    none
    path_checker    readsector0
    rr_min_io    100
    max_fds    8192
    rr_weight    priorities
    failback    immediate
    no_path_retry    fail
    user_friendly_names    yes
}
blacklist {
    wwid    26353900f02796769
    devnode    "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"
    devnode    "^hd[a-z]"
}
devices {
        device {
            vendor    "COMPAQ "
            product    "HSV110 (C)COMPAQ"
            path_grouping_policy    multibus
            getuid_callout    "/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n"
            path_checker    readsector0
            path_selector    "round-robin 0"
            hardware_handler    "0"
            failback    15
            rr_weight    priorities
            no_path_retry    queue
        }
        device {
            vendor    "COMPAQ "
            product    "MSA1000 "
            path_grouping_policy    multibus
        }
}
```

But my function only goes "2 layers" deep what if there is something like the deivces { device { item{ } }} Any idea how to make the function more universal ?

Comment: I think you are looking for `import json` and `json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4)`. pprint can also do some nice stuff like this.

Comment: I know it looks like Json but its not, the output needs to look like the above example that it produce now, no additional brackets, "", :, {} and so on...

Comment: Thats gonna be tricky. Why not convert it to yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion!

You need to write your function such that it can call itself:

```
INDENT_STEP = 4


def print_indented(indent, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Prints anything with `indent` spaces before it.
    Passes arguments to builtin print.
    """
    print((" " * indent), *args, **kwargs)


def print_list(items, indent):
    print("{")
    for value in items:
        print_formatted(value, indent)
    print_indented(indent, "}")


def print_dict(dictionary, indent):
    """Prints each key and value of a dictionary, separated by a space."""
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        child_indent = indent + INDENT_STEP
        print_indented(child_indent, key, "", end="")
        print_formatted(value, child_indent)


def print_formatted(item, indent=0):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        print_list(item, indent)
        return

    if isinstance(item, dict):
        print_dict(item, indent)
        return

    print(item)
```

Comment: I like this, easy to understand. One issue though. It treats the first "list" with { and end wit } the first so the output is offset by one indentation and start with { and and with } I have fixed this with see the code here: https://pastebin.com/PveLrX5T which produce almost perfect results, however it would be nice to control how much space there is between each key and value. like here `vendor    "COMPAQ ` currently there is only one space and I did not figure out yet how to change it just for this combination without affecting the space in front of each {

Comment: If you want to control spaces between vendor and compact. Look at my code in the first answer. In the line `" "*4*indent, key, " "*(30-len(key)), val))` 30 is the distance from the beginning of the line. Try the code and you'll see it's exactly the output you're looking for.

Comment: @VladoPortos If you need more spaces between the key and value, you can adjust `print_dict` (either directly or parametrizing it) so that the third argument for `print_indented` is a bunch of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) package. Try this:

```
import json

d = [{'blacklist': [{'devnode': '"^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"'}, {'devnode': '"^hd[a-z][[0-9]*]"'}, {'devnode': '"^cciss!c[0-9]d[0-9]*"'}]}, {'defaults': [{'user_friendly_names': 'yes'}]}, {'defaults': [{'udev_dir': '/dev'}, {'polling_interval': '10'}, {'selector': '"round-robin 0"'}, {'path_grouping_policy': 'multibus'}, {'getuid_callout': '"/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n"'}, {'prio_callout': 'none'}, {'path_checker': 'readsector0'}, {'rr_min_io': '100'}, {'max_fds': '8192'}, {'rr_weight': 'priorities'}, {'failback': 'immediate'}, {'no_path_retry': 'fail'}, {'user_friendly_names': 'yes'}]}, {'blacklist': [{'wwid': '26353900f02796769'}, {'devnode': '"^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"'}, {'devnode': '"^hd[a-z]"'}]}, {'devices': [{'device': [{'vendor': '"COMPAQ "'}, {'product': '"HSV110 (C)COMPAQ"'}, {'path_grouping_policy': 'multibus'}, {'getuid_callout': '"/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n"'}, {'path_checker': 'readsector0'}, {'path_selector': '"round-robin 0"'}, {'hardware_handler': '"0"'}, {'failback': '15'}, {'rr_weight': 'priorities'}, {'no_path_retry': 'queue'}]}, {'device': [{'vendor': '"COMPAQ "'}, {'product': '"MSA1000 "'}, {'path_grouping_policy': 'multibus'}]}]}]

print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
```

where the `json.dumps` command takes the dictionary `d` and indents 4 whitespace chars per indentation (or your choosing of course).

EDIT:

If you want the output to look exactly as in your question, the following recursive function should do it:

```
def parse(data, indent=0):
    if not isinstance(data, list):
        data = [data]

    for d in data:
        for key, val in d.items():
            if isinstance(val, list):
                print(" "*4*indent + key + "{ ")
                parse(val, indent + 1)
                print(" "*4*indent + "}")
            else:
                print("{}{}{}{}" .format(
                    " "*4*indent, key, " "*(30-len(key)), val))

data = [{'blacklist': [{'devnode': '"^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"'}, {'devnode': '"^hd[a-z][[0-9]*]"'}, {'devnode': '"^cciss!c[0-9]d[0-9]*"'}]}, {'defaults': [{'user_friendly_names': 'yes'}]}, {'defaults': [{'udev_dir': '/dev'}, {'polling_interval': '10'}, {'selector': '"round-robin 0"'}, {'path_grouping_policy': 'multibus'}, {'getuid_callout': '"/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n"'}, {'prio_callout': 'none'}, {'path_checker': 'readsector0'}, {'rr_min_io': '100'}, {'max_fds': '8192'}, {'rr_weight': 'priorities'}, {'failback': 'immediate'}, {'no_path_retry': 'fail'}, {'user_friendly_names': 'yes'}]}, {'blacklist': [{'wwid': '26353900f02796769'}, {'devnode': '"^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"'}, {'devnode': '"^hd[a-z]"'}]}, {'devices': [{'device': [{'vendor': '"COMPAQ "'}, {'product': '"HSV110 (C)COMPAQ"'}, {'path_grouping_policy': 'multibus'}, {'getuid_callout': '"/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n"'}, {'path_checker': 'readsector0'}, {'path_selector': '"round-robin 0"'}, {'hardware_handler': '"0"'}, {'failback': '15'}, {'rr_weight': 'priorities'}, {'no_path_retry': 'queue'}]}, {'device': [{'vendor': '"COMPAQ "'}, {'product': '"MSA1000 "'}, {'path_grouping_policy': 'multibus'}]}]}]

parse(data)
```

Comment: Merely to quickly show OP that he can add whatever separators he has (I sometimes stumble upon API returns with json formatted text containing other separators, though one would argue it's not json, but anyway). It is indeed not needed in this case. Coming to think of it, I'll remove it, perhaps it's only confusing. Thanks.

Comment: No issues with it. I have just never seen it used before so I was curious of the rational; however, what you said makes sense. (I used json.dumps to reformat his question but now I think I will revert it).

Comment: I linked to docs.python, so OP can still read more about usage there, so I still agree that it is unnecessary in the answer :) I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Guys I know it looks like Json, but its not, pprint and json.dump is producing way more quotations, {} and other stuff than I need, it does not look like the output I posted.  It needs to be exactly as in example...